# A very long time to load the site

Tags: performance, apache, dns, timeout, html

Help me find the reason why before downloading any of the pages is a delay of about 2 minutes, and then abruptly loaded site. No changes to the site did not do throughout the year. Before, everything was fine, 2 weeks ago is started. Site: www.proudandcurvy.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

It's probably some kind of DNS timeout, is the web server configured to do DNS lookups? You really want to turn that off.

You use the Apache HTTPD, the configuration option that you should be looking for is

**HostnameLookups** and it should be set to **Off**.

Comment: Did you check the error log? It's usually located at /var/log/apache/error.log